# Why are limits introduced when integrating both sides? Proof for solving Exact Differential Equations.

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, proof-explanation

I was reading Ordinary Differential Equations by Morris Tenenbaum and Harry Pollard, and have spent significant time trying to understand the **'Proof of sufficient condition', for exact differential equations**. In this proof a formula to solve exact differential equations is derived:

Given the exact differential equation:

$p(x, y)dx\; + \; q(x, y)dy = 0$

The solution is:

$f(x, y) = \int_{x_0}^{x}p(x, y)dx \; + \int_{y_0}^{y}q(x_0, y)dy$

$f(x, y) = c$

There is a step in the begining of the proof; as $q(x,y)$ is the partial derivative of $f(x, y)$, with respect to $x$:

$f(x, y) = \int_{x_0}^{x} p(x, y) \; + \; R(y)$

Later in the proof, we find that:

$\int_{x_0}^{x}\frac{\partial }{\partial x}q(x, y)dx \; + R'(y) = q(x, y)$

$R'(y) = q(x_0, y)$

$R(y) = \int_{y_0}^{y} q(x_0, y) dy$

The Question:
What I don't understand is why, when integrating both sides, they introduce the limits $x$ and $x_0$. Where is $x_0$ from? Later, they set $x_0=0$. Why is that allowed?

Does it have something to do with the domain of the functions?

Furthermore, later, it is introduced that you can solve these equations without a formula. Where you simply integrate $p(x, y)$ and find $R(y)$ without integrating with limits- I hope I have explained that well. That method is shown on this website https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/exact.aspx#mjx-eqn-eqeq5. Why am I not using limits here?